# Is insurance compensation for lost wages taxable (in the U.S.)?

Tags: united-states, insurance, salary, payroll-taxes

Recently I was involved in an automobile accident. I missed some time from work and now have to take time off to go to physical therapy. Injury coverage from the auto insurance is compensating me for most (85%) of the lost salary. The first check just arrived, and no taxes were withheld. So that I know if I should set some money aside for a possible tax bill in the future, I'm wondering if (in the U.S.) this is considered taxable income.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, wages are taxable, and insurance payouts for lost wages are also taxable.

They aren't required to withhold taxes, but they will give you a 1099 (if under $600 they aren't required to file a 1099, but likely will anyway).

[IRS Publication 4345](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p4345.pdf) outlines the tax implications of settlements.